# How are we allowed to judge Korach?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, dor-hamidbar

When listening to numerous rabbis showing their intellectual and religious superiority to the leading figures of Dor Hamidbar (not limited to), claiming to know the right answers and behaviors the former didn't, I wondered how are they allowed to do so?

The Gemora (Shabbos 112) claims that "אם ראשונים כמלאכים אנו כבני אדם" - "if we are humans, our ancestors are like angels" - attaining much higher spiritual levels.

I compare this to, say, kindergarten kids criticizing our Prime Mister for his interior policy.

Why are we allowed to speak so judgmentally and frivolously about the leaders of the generation that allegedly excels the level of Olam Habah?

And I don't only mean our generation but even the Rishonim - how dare they? I believe, that the way we're restricted from criticizing them, they are restricted in criticising Dor Hamidbar?

Comment: Your last paragraph seems a little hypocritical... you’re claiming that we’re not allowed to criticize the rishonim, and yet you criticize them for criticizing dor hamidbar.

Comment: It would also help to know which criticism(s) in particular you had in mind.

Comment: @Loani 1. "קשוט עצמך ואחר כך קשוט אחרים" (B"B 60) Rishonim should be obligated by the Gemmorah not less than us 2. Being arrogant, selfish, greedy etc.

Comment: Good question! Indeed we are not even supposed to criticize Lot's daughters: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96386/is-it-considered-a-good-thing-that-lots-daughters-slept-with-their-father?r=SearchResults